# Can't refer to models in callback function registered to user_logged_in signal in Django

Tags: django, django-signals

I have a requirement to write a DB row when a user logs in.  The following code is in models.py (at end of file, after model definitions);

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
from utils import *
def rec_login(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
    u_audit('some text here', user)    

user_logged_in.connect(rec_login)
```

There's a utilities module which is imported in modules.py.  The following code is called in utils.py from the above function;

**utils.py**

```
from app.models import *
def u_audit(msg,u):
    ua=UserLog(action=msg, user=u, actiontime=datetime.now())
    ua.save()
```

I'm reusing the u_audit() function in several other places (post-login).

When a user logs in, I get a NameError for the UserLog object (i.e. it looks like the model definitions can't be accessed by the signal callback function).

The UserLog object referred to above is just a simple models.Model.

Anyone know what I'm missing?

I've tried putting a simple file write in the callback function in models.py and tried the same thing in the u_audit() function. instead and that works fine, so I know it's being called properly.  I've got other signal callback functions registered (all post-login) and they're using models and working fine.

Comment: did you import ``UserLog`` in utils.py?

Comment: Yes - it's a models.Model which is included in the **from app.models import ** *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a circular import? Utils refers to models and models to utils - it will not work. Please change utils.py to:

```
def u_audit(msg,u):
    from app.models import UserLog
    ua=UserLog(action=msg, user=u, actiontime=datetime.now())
    ua.save()
```

But also something like that suggest that maybe models.py is good place for u_audit and you should just move it there.

Comment: ...sigh...
Yes - thank you.  Clearly been staring at this code too long.  You're exactly right - the issue was caused by over-zealous importing.  I've narrowed down to only the imports needed for the specific **utils** calls in **models.py**.  **utils.py** was also doing `from models import *`, so yes - a circular reference.  I found it a bit odd that Python/Django didn't complain in any way other than the error described above, but I'm not really familiar enough with them to know whether I should have expected that.

For future ref this is Python 2.6.6 with Django 1.4.

Comment: Don't worry, I always find them hard to spot too, and I saw a lots of them ;) And I agree that the way Python reports it are not very helpful, but if you dig into how Python imports works it becomes clear why it is this particular error.